# Как нарисовать N-конечную звезду QPainter

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qthread, qpainter

Как нарисовать ***`N-конечную звезду`***, которая всегда в центре родительского блока через `QPainter`, зная только *радиус* описанной окружности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заполняйте поля и нажимайте на кнопку. Рисуйте любый звезды в любом количестве.

```
import sys
import math
import random   
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *


class Worker(QThread):
    output = pyqtSignal(QRect, QImage)     

    def __init__(self, angle, outerRadius, innerRadius, parent = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.angle, self.outerRadius, self.innerRadius = angle, outerRadius, innerRadius
        self.refresh(self.angle, self.outerRadius, self.innerRadius)

    def __del__(self):
        self.exiting = True
        self.wait()        

    def render(self, size, stars):
        self.size  = size
        self.stars = stars
        self.start()

    def refresh(self, angle, outerRadius, innerRadius): 
        self.angle, self.outerRadius, self.innerRadius = angle, outerRadius, innerRadius
        self.exiting = False
        self.size    = QSize(0, 0)
        self.stars   = 0

        # Каждая звезда рисуется с использованием QPainterPath, которую мы определяем заранее:
        self.path = QPainterPath()
        angle     = 2 * math.pi / self.angle               
        self.path.moveTo(self.outerRadius, 0)
        for step in range(1, self.angle+1):    
            self.path.lineTo(
                self.innerRadius * math.cos((step - 0.5) * angle),
                self.innerRadius * math.sin((step - 0.5) * angle)
                )
            self.path.lineTo(
                self.outerRadius * math.cos(step * angle),
                self.outerRadius * math.sin(step * angle)
                )
        self.path.closeSubpath()

    def run(self):
        # Примечание: это никогда не вызывается напрямую. 
        random.seed()
        n      = self.stars
        width  = self.size.width()
        height = self.size.height()

        while not self.exiting and n > 0:
            image = QImage(self.outerRadius * 2, self.outerRadius * 2,
                           QImage.Format_ARGB32)
            image.fill(qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0))

            x     = random.randrange(0, width)
            y     = random.randrange(0, height)
            angle = random.randrange(0, 360)
            red   = random.randrange(0, 256)
            green = random.randrange(0, 256)
            blue  = random.randrange(0, 256)
            alpha = random.randrange(0, 256)

            painter = QPainter()
            painter.begin(image)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
            painter.setBrush(QColor(red, green, blue, alpha))
            painter.translate(self.outerRadius, self.outerRadius)
            painter.rotate(angle)
            painter.drawPath(self.path)
            painter.end()

            self.output.emit(QRect(x - self.outerRadius, y - self.outerRadius,
                                   self.outerRadius * 2, self.outerRadius * 2), 
                                   image)
            n -= 1


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)  

        label = QLabel("Количество звезд:")
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(10000)
        self.spinBox.setValue(50)
        self.spinBox2 = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox2.setRange(4, 10)
        self.spinBox2.setValue(5)
        self.spinBox3 = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox3.setRange(30, 70)
        self.spinBox3.setValue(50)
        self.spinBox4 = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox4.setRange(8, 20)

        self.startButton = QPushButton("&Start")
        self.viewer      = QLabel()
        self.viewer.setFixedSize(700, 500)        

        self.thread = Worker(5, 50, 8)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.updateUi)
        # Сигнал пользовательского вывода (QRect, QImage) подключается к слоту addImage(), 
        # чтобы мы могли обновлять метку зрителя каждый раз, когда нарисована новая звезда.
        self.thread.output.connect(self.addImage)

        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.makePicture)  

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Количество вершин у звезды:"), 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox2, 1, 1)        
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Внешний радиус звезды:"), 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox3, 2, 1) 
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Внутренний радиус звезды:"), 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox4, 3, 1)         
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton, 0, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.viewer,      5, 0, 1, 3)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Пример рисования звезд.")

    def makePicture(self):
        # refresh
        self.thread.refresh(self.spinBox2.value(), self.spinBox3.value(), self.spinBox4.value()) 

        self.spinBox.setReadOnly(True)
        self.startButton.setEnabled(False)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.viewer.size())
        pixmap.fill(Qt.black)
        self.viewer.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.thread.render(self.viewer.size(), self.spinBox.value())        

    # Всякий раз, когда звезда нарисована рабочим потоком, он будет излучать сигнал, 
    # который подключен к слоту addImage(). Этот слот вызывается с значением QRect, указывающим, 
    # где звезда должна быть помещена в пиксельную карту, удерживаемую меткой зрителя, 
    # и изображение самой звезды:
    def addImage(self, rect, image):
        pixmap  = self.viewer.pixmap()
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(pixmap)
        painter.drawImage(rect, image)
        painter.end()
        self.viewer.update(rect)

    # Слот updateUi() вызывается, когда поток прекращает работу. Поскольку мы обычно хотим, 
    # чтобы пользователь снова запускал поток, мы перезапускаем пользовательский интерфейс, 
    # чтобы активировать кнопку запуска:
    def updateUi(self):
        self.spinBox.setReadOnly(False)
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)   
        pixmap  = self.viewer.pixmap()
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(pixmap)
        painter.setPen(QColor(255, 0, 0))           
        painter.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 25))        
        painter.drawText(QRect(80, 100, 150, 50), Qt.AlignCenter, "The END")
        painter.end()
        self.viewer.update()          


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]